# SVG fragment identifiers are swapped in Safari when served through webapp

Tags: html, svg, safari

*I have replicated my problem in the following simple example*

I have a simple webpage like the following:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>  
        <img src="icons.svg#close"></img>
        <br>
        <img src="icons.svg#error"></img>
    </body>
</html>
```

Viewing this page locally in Safari, the page renders correctly:

[image: Correct rendering]

where the close icon appears above the error icon.

---

However, when I serve the file with NodeJS webapp (or use the `python SimpleHTTPServer` command) and view it in Safari, then the images are in each other's places:

[image: In correct rendering]

even though the dom still looks correct, and the `src` attributes of each `img` tag hold the correct paths.

---

Here is the `icons.svg` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <style>:root>svg{display:none}:root>svg:target{display:block}</style>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 12 12" enable-background="new 0 0 12 12" id="close">
        <path d="M7.2 6l4.5-4.4c.4-.4.4-.9 0-1.3s-.9-.4-1.3 0L6 4.7 1.6.3C1.2-.1.7-.1.3.3s-.4.9 0 1.3L4.7 6 .3 10.4c-.4.4-.4.9 0 1.3.2.2.4.3.6.3s.5-.1.7-.3L6 7.3l4.4 4.4c.2.2.4.3.7.3.2 0 .5-.1.7-.3.4-.4.4-.9 0-1.3L7.2 6z" opacity=".3" enable-background="new"/>
    </svg>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 58 46" enable-background="new 0 0 58 46" id="error">
        <style type="text/css">.st0{fill:#ff9141}.st1{fill:#fff}</style>
        <path class="st0" d="M30.6 1c-.9-1.4-2.3-1.4-3.2 0L.4 43.5C-.5 44.9.2 46 1.8 46h54.4c1.7 0 2.3-1.1 1.4-2.5L30.6 1z"/>
        <path class="st1" d="M26.3 15.2h5.5V30h-5.5zM26.3 33.5h5.5v5.3h-5.5z"/>
    </svg>
</svg>
```

---

The page is rendered correctly in all of the other browsers, regardless of if the file is being loaded locally or served through a server.

Comment: Very, very strange. I'm getting the same behaviour when the files are accessed from an Apache webserver too.

Comment: i tried with few webservers available, i can't reproduce this behaviour. can it be caused by your webserver not serving icons.svg file on time, so browser decides not to wait and try next icon and then svg is available?

Comment: Without having Safari to test on, it could also possibly be an HTTP header Content-Type problem.

Comment: @tyler have you tried Safari 9? It seems to have got worse - `:target` seems to do nothing at all (never matched), and the test page I linked to in my answer gives differently wrong results for everything except using an svg for `background-image` with `background-position`, which now seems correct

Comment: I have not tried in Safari 9.  Thanks for mentioning that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to incomplete/buggy SVG fragment CSS support in Safari. Browser support for this technique is still relatively patchy - see https://css-tricks.com/svg-fragment-identifiers-work/

> Current versions of Chrome/Safari/Opera (38/8/25) handle all the HTML  techniques well, but none of the CSS techniques, including the background-position one.

Here's how my Safari 8 (left) and Chrome (right) render the test page - note that the icons should go [image] every time:

[image]

Some experiments with your content follow:

If I repeat the pair of images a second time, the fourth image is somehow a composite of the two (below left). No interpretation of your svg should ever be able to produce an image like this. Interestingly, I get exactly the same split if you use different styling properties, e.g. opacity (below right):

[image] [image: opacity version]

If I zoom in and out with <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>, the overlaps and partial images change.

[image] [image]

Resizing the page also has an effect.

Speculating that the styling of the images might somehow be interacting with one another, I tried having four different copies of the image (`icons1.svg#close`, `icons2.svg#error` etc.) and referring to them separately. This mostly fixed the problem, but the fourth image was missing the bottom three quarters. However, as soon as I resized the window, the missing part of the image appeared.

Bottom line: incomplete/buggy svg fragment identifier/CSS handling.